# Search for wrapped packages/procedures in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

A simple question but a google and SO search hasn't turned anything up.

Does anyone know if it is possible to search in the Oracle Data Dictionary to find all wrapped (that have been obfuscated using the 'wrap' utility) packages/procedures?

Thanks,
John.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to check the first line of the source code:

```
select type, owner, name
from all_source
where line = 1
  and instr(text, 'wrapped') > 1;
```

Except for very long wrapped packages, wrapped types usually have the whole code in one row (line 1) while unwrapped types have a separate row for each line of source code.

Answer (score 1):

Searching the text '*wrapped*' on line 1 using all_source/user_source does show wrapped objects. But this could break if a unit name itself contains the text 'wrapped', you could instead use :

```
select u.object_name
  from sys.procedure$ p, user_objects u
 where u.object_id = obj#
   AND bitand(p.options, 2) <> 0;
```

Full database object view :

```
select d.owner,
       d.object_name,
       case bitand(p.options, 2)
         when 0 then
          'PLAIN'
         else
          'WRAPPED'
       end wrapped
  from sys.procedure$ p, dba_objects d
 where d.object_id = obj#
   and d.owner = USER;
```

Comment: I suspect Oracle DBs may have changed a little in the decade since I first asked this question.